# How to Filter a collection with specific date range in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product, filter

How to filter a collection with specific column name from and to in Magento2?
For example:

```
  $fromdate = 2022-10-23 00:00:00;
  $todate  =  2022-10-25 00:00:00
  $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
```

How can I get the collection between $fromdate to $todate ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you

```
addAttributeToFilter('column_name', array('from'=>'2022-10-23 00:00:00', 'to'=>'2022-10-24 00:00:00'));
```